# SQL Database Not Updating

Tags: php, mysql

ive been stuck here can anyone help? the first page updates then the subsequent pages do not update. I think the problem might be that the next page isnt keeping track of the id i think. i'm a beginner, so im still struggling with the concepts.

Here are the code.

index.php

```
<?php
include 'includes/config.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Focused Plastic Mink" />
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <style data-tag="reset-style-sheet">
      html {  line-height: 1.15;}body {  margin: 0;}* {  box-sizing: border-box;  border-width: 0;  border-style: solid;}p,li,ul,pre,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea {  font-family: inherit;  font-size: 100%;  line-height: 1.15;  margin: 0;}button,select {  text-transform: none;}button,[type="button"],[type="reset"],[type="submit"] {  -webkit-appearance: button;}button::-moz-focus-inner,[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {  border-style: none;  padding: 0;}button:-moz-focus,[type="button"]:-moz-focus,[type="reset"]:-moz-focus,[type="submit"]:-moz-focus {  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;}a {  color: inherit;  text-decoration: inherit;}input {  padding: 2px 4px;}img {  display: block;}html { scroll-behavior: smooth  }
    </style>
    <style data-tag="default-style-sheet">
      html {
        font-family: Inter;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      body {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style:normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: 1.15;
        color: var(--dl-color-gray-black);
        background-color: var(--dl-color-gray-white);

      }
    </style>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
      data-tag="font"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <link href="./home.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <div class="home-container">
        <div class="home-container1">
          <div class="home-container2">
            <img
              alt="image"
              src="public/playground_assets/ezgif.com-gif-maker%20%5B1%5D-200h.png"
              class="home-image"
            />
            <form class="home-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>/includes/process.php">
              <h1 class="home-text">Enter Your Details</h1>
              <input
                type="text"
                required
                placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
                name="fname"
                class="home-textinput input"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                required
                placeholder="Enter Your Last Name"
                name="lname"
                class="home-textinput1 input"
              />
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
              <button type="submit" name="action" value="first" class="home-button button">Next</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is the next page

next.php

```
<?php
include 'includes/config.php';
if(!isset($_GET['r'])){
    header('Location: '.$baseURL);
    exit();
}
else{
    $ref = sterilize($_GET['r']);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Focused Plastic Mink" />
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <style data-tag="reset-style-sheet">
      html {  line-height: 1.15;}body {  margin: 0;}* {  box-sizing: border-box;  border-width: 0;  border-style: solid;}p,li,ul,pre,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea {  font-family: inherit;  font-size: 100%;  line-height: 1.15;  margin: 0;}button,select {  text-transform: none;}button,[type="button"],[type="reset"],[type="submit"] {  -webkit-appearance: button;}button::-moz-focus-inner,[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {  border-style: none;  padding: 0;}button:-moz-focus,[type="button"]:-moz-focus,[type="reset"]:-moz-focus,[type="submit"]:-moz-focus {  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;}a {  color: inherit;  text-decoration: inherit;}input {  padding: 2px 4px;}img {  display: block;}html { scroll-behavior: smooth  }
    </style>
    <style data-tag="default-style-sheet">
      html {
        font-family: Inter;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      body {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style:normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: 1.15;
        color: var(--dl-color-gray-black);
        background-color: var(--dl-color-gray-white);

      }
    </style>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
      data-tag="font"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <link href="./home.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <div class="home-container">
        <div class="home-container1">
          <div class="home-container2">
            <img
              alt="image"
              src="public/playground_assets/ezgif.com-gif-maker%20%5B1%5D-200h.png"
              class="home-image"
            />
            <form class="home-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>/includes/process.php">
              <h1 class="home-text">Log In to Msport</h1>
              <input
                type="password"
                required
                placeholder="Password"
                class="home-textinput input"
              />
              <input
                type="number"
                required
                placeholder="+234 | Enter Phone Number"
                class="home-textinput1 input"
              />
              <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="<?php echo $ref; ?>">
              <button type="submit" name="action" value="second" class="home-button button">Next</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the php file handling the processes.

process.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST)){
    extract($_POST);


    if($action == 'first'){
        $fname = sterilize($fname);
        $lname = sterilize($lname);

        $stmt = $db->query('INSERT INTO entries (fname, lname, date_added) VALUES ("'.$fname.'", "'.$lname.'", now())');
        if($stmt){
            $id = $db->lastInsertId();
            header('Location: '.$baseURL.'/next?r='.$id);
            exit();
        }
    }





    if($action == 'second'){
        $ref = sterilize($ref);
        $id = $db->lastInsertId();
        $phone_number = sterilize($phone_number);
        $password = sterilize($password);

        $stmt = $db->query('UPDATE entries SET phone_number = "'.$phone_number.'", password = "'.$password.'" WHERE id = "'.$ref.'"');
        if($stmt){
            $id = $db->lastInsertId();
            header('Location: '.$baseURL.'/pin?r='.$ref);
            exit();
        }
    }


    if($action == 'final'){
        $ref = sterilize($ref);
        

        $pin = sterilize($pin);

        $stmt = $db->query('UPDATE entries SET pin = "'.$pin.'" WHERE MD5(id) = "'.$ref.'"');

        if($stmt){
            header('Location: '.$baseURL.'/error');
        }
        else{
            header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REFERER']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, please fix your sql injection vulnerabilities and stop writing code wth sql injection vulnerabilities right away.  it's a travesty that in 2022 people are still writing code this way.  yes I realize you call `sterilize` but it's still the wrong way to set query parameters

Comment: Did the answer work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inputs here need names

```html
              <input
                type="password"
                required
                placeholder="Password"
                class="home-textinput input"
                name="password"
              />
              <input
                type="number"
                required
                placeholder="+234 | Enter Phone Number"
                class="home-textinput1 input"
                name="phone_number"
              />
```

Also, note that multiple people will be using it simultaneously. The sessions are stateless.  So the **lastInsertId** may be for a different user .

It would be better if you had all the inputs on the same page. If you do want multiple pages, then you need to pass the id from the first page to the second, perhaps as a hidden input.